# What is the "untagged" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is [untagged](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) automatically added to questions with empty tag lists?

How is it possible those questions came about in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall reading (on meta.SO or the blog) that it happens when a question's only tag is deleted.

Comment: Or, more likely, on migrated questions.

Comment: Correct. When a tag is deleted, the question can be left with only the "untagged" tag. Same goes on for migrated questions where the tag is banned (and thus removed).